# Mulitple preprocessor directives on shared project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, preprocessor-directive

I have a shared database model in a seperate project, that is shared with another solution, however i want to use a different Identity mapping, so i wanted to know if it possible to use preprocessor directives.

Inside sharedProject example:

```
#if setup1
    public  virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

#elif setup2
    public  virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
#endif
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

I know you can add preprocessor directives to the project, but not entirely sure how that works, only used it for debug.
In:

```
Project -> Properties -> build -> Conditional preprocessor symbols
```

Should i do something like this:

```
StartupProject1 -> properties -> Conditional preprocossor symbols = setup1
StartupProject2 -> properties -> Conditional preprocossor symbols = setup2
sharedProject -> properties -> Conditional preprocossor symbols = setup1,setup2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out how to do it
I ended up using configuration mananger, and create multiple configurations, based, on those configurations, i just added the only needed preprocsessor symbol

SharedProject Setup1 Configuration

```
SharedProject -> properties -> Conditional preprocossor symbols = setup1
```

SharedProject Setup2 Configuration

```
SharedProject -> properties -> Conditional preprocossor symbols = setup2
```

And in configuration manager on the solution, i just chose the needed setup for the shared project